# Python Regex remove comments or numbers in brackets

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove line numbers and comments using regex, but it does not work just yet:

```
import re
string = """(1) At what time.!? [asdf] School-
(2) bus. So late, already.!? [ghjk]"""

#res = re.sub(r"[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", string)

res = re.sub("(\d+) ","", res)
res = re.sub("[.*]","", res)
res = re.sub(r"-\s","", res)
res = re.sub(r"[^\w\säüöß]","", res)
res = re.sub("-\n","", res)
print(res.split())
```

So I was trying to remove anything in brackets () and [] with my #commented line, but then I am stuck with a whitespace starting of each line.
Then I decided to split it up and came up the the five re.sub methods.

Result should be like this:

```
['At', 'what', 'time', 'Schoolbus', 'So', 'late', 'already']
```

I am stuck with the Linenumbers not being removed, although they are in () and should be gone. Which then causes my res.sub() for connecting words with "-" from school- bus to schoolbus to not work aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `sub + findall` solution:

```sh
import re

string = """(1) At what time.!? [asdf] School-
(2) bus. So late, already.!? [ghjk]"""

print (re.findall(r'\b\w+(?:-\w+)*', re.sub(r'(\([^)]*\)|\[[^]]*\]|-)\s*', '', string)))
```

**Output:**

```
['At', 'what', 'time', 'Schoolbus', 'So', 'late', 'already']
```

**Details:**

- `re.sub(r'(\([^)]*\)|\[[^]]*\]|-)\s*', '', string)`: Removes all `(...)` and `[...]` or `-` strings followed by 0 or more spaces
- `\b\w+`: Matches 1+ word characters starting with a word boundary